Kona Precept Front QR stuck
The quick release does release tension with handle as it should.  No matter how many times I spin QR counter clockwise it will not pull from axle sleeve.
Advice ?

Is this a QR skewer or a through axle?

Sometimes when the skewer is bent it is hard to remove from the axle.

It is probably stuck to the hub bearing with corrosion. Test: as you unscrew it, are the fork legs being pushed apart (a gap opening up between hub and left fork leg)?

Does the quick release look like this?

If so, you have a somewhat odd but perfectly functional type of quick release axle called a Maxle Light.  To remove it, open the qr lever ALL the way, and orient it such that the backside of the lever is fitted into the notch on the axle. Then, you can use the lever as a handle to unscrew the axle.
https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/ax-lte-mxlf-a1

Hey @VladimirFГероямслава I’m pretty that the Kona Precept was that caliber of bike.

@PaulH Actually yes, the link in Criggie's answer was clear in this. I  was not looking at that link but searched and I saw a different model https://archive.konaworld.com/archive/2017/precept_120.cfm and then searched for RockShox FS 30 120mm https://www.sram.com/en/service/models/fs-30s-tk-a4 and it said  9 mm quick release.  BTW, I have the same Rockshox thru axle, so I am familiar with this type. The edges can get worn, unfortunately.

The published specs for this model-range show it dates from 2014 through 2018
https://archive.konaworld.com/archive/2016/precept_150.cfm

Specs at that page say only

Front Hub Shimano Deore QR15
Rear Hub  Shimano Deore 142x12mm

So its probably a quick release skewer.

I see X failure modes

The acorn nut on the far side from the lever, has damage such that the thread is stuck to the skewer.  Could be rust or the serrations are worn smooth.  Solution: use pliers or vice grips to hold the but while turning the lever.
The lever may have become unbonded to the skewer's shaft and is just rotating.  Try clamping hard  enough with vice grips to deform the hinge and gain some purchase.  You might be able to bend the QR shaft enough to get leverage, or worst case disassemble/cut through the hinge and allow the shaft to extract out the other side.  Cover your brake rotor well!

No matter the cause, you should replace the QR skewer.  They're not expensive.

I interpret QR15 to mean cammed thru-axle 15 mm in diameter, the which is also what I’d expect from a fork with that much travel from that era.

@PaulH After zooming in on the picture, I agree. That’s definitely a Maxle Lite. Plus I’ve never heard of a bike specced from the factory with TA rear and QR front.

@PaulH fair point, sounds reasonable.   I'm also trying to "show the working"

@Criggie, I hear ya. Also “crammed” should have been “cammed”

@PaulH fixed !!

@Criggie thanks!
